# Using a C++ library in Google Native Client

Tags: c++, google-nativeclient

I am completely new to Native Client and unfortunately I am also quite inexperienced with 'make', compiling etc., so I hope you may give me some basic information on how to approach my 
problem.

So what I am trying to accomplish is compiling a C++ library for using it in a NaCl application.

First I have my application based on the examples delivered with Pepper, which I simply compile using the attached 'make.bat'.

Well then I downloaded the source code of the library, containing folders like 'config' and 'src', so first i would have to call 'configure', 'make', 'make install'. But i would like to let the library compile with that 'make.bat', so I guess I would have to append the complex configure/Makefile scripts of the library to the Makefile of my NaCl application?
How can that be done?
Where can i find useful information and/or help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can look to [nacl ports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/) project to see how porting libraries to NaCl can be done. NaCl ports works best on Linux platform, so you better have a virtual machine with it or work on it directly.

There is one more trick to port libraries. People create wrapper scripts around compiler and linker. These wrapper scripts call nacl compiler and linker but they also create a shell script that calls the resulting NaCl executable using sel_ldr. This script is returned instead of executable (this is Linux-only trick). This way configure and make can execute NaCl code and do not suspect anything. So normal configure/make process can be used, we just need to set compiler and linker to these wrapper scripts.

Since you are probably not going to develop library itself, it is best to compile it once and then use it in your makefile. Add `-l` option with the name of your library and `-L` option with path to library directory. You can use `GLIBC_LDFLAGS` variable in the example makefile for these options.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you can use Visual Studio to developer NaCl applications?

http://mainroach.blogspot.com/2012/10/official-nacl-vs2010-add-in-available.html